# Does ROC AUC different between crossval and test set indicate overfitting or other problem?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, cross-validation, overfitting

I am training a composite model (XGBoost, Linear Regression, and RandomForest) to predict injured people probability. Well, the results of cross-validation with 5 folds. Well, I can see any problem related to overfitting since the metrics are almost equal for each fold and the test set. However, this is not true for ROC AUC, as you can see above. This same behavior happens on neat models.

The question is: does this situation indicate some problem or I can use the model without major concerns?

Libraries: scikit-learn and XBGoost.

[image: Cross-validation results for a composite model]

Comment: Seems like you just have some statistical variance, I don't see the problem

Comment: @CarlosMougan the drop in roc_auc seems rather large for that, no? That it is so consistent across folds, and that every other metric is quite consistent between cv and test but this one isn't, does seem surprising to me.

Comment: I can say that roc_auc is notably different from the rest: the top four are hard classification metrics operating (presumably) on the default threshold of 0.5, and the last two are continuous losses based on the probability scores, while the ROC is based solely on the rank-ordering.  It's not clear to me though whether it should be concerning; ideally, identify the right metric for your problem and stick to that?

Comment: @BenReiniger, this is the point. I saw this difference and ask myself if I need to be concerned about it. From my perspective, the model has a good balance present by F1 and a good probability prediction by its Brier score and log loss score.

Comment: How many samples do you have each fold? and how much the test set?

Comment: I understand that the crossvalidation folds and the test set are sampled coming from the same distribution, right? One sanity check can be to do univariate test between the features in CV and test to see if they have the same distribution.

Comment: Are you measuring using predict? or predict_proba? AUC accepts soft predictions

Comment: @CarlosMougan:
Total rows data set: 68223
Rows in the training set: 47756
Rows in each fold: 9551
Rows in testing set: 20467

Comment: @CarlosMougan, I don't know if will answer this correctly, but, I believe they came from the same distribution since the response variable is unbalanced and I set it to stratify by y.

Comment: @CarlosMougan, I believe you found the problem! I incorrectly use the **roc_auc_score** function. I will fix it!

Comment: @CarlosMougan As it sounds like your guess was good, can you expand that into an answer? Or maybe Greg can? (The term "soft predictions" is unfamiliar to me - is it specific to scikit-learn?)

Comment: @DarrenCook I am not sure if it really answers OP question

Comment: In binary classification soft prediction is model.predict_proba instead of model.predict